# Can you charge a Quick Charge 3.0 phone with a Quick Charge 2.0 mains adapter?

Tags: battery, charging

The Wileyfox Swift 2 is QC3.0 enabled, but the only trusted brand adapter I can get is QC2.0. What happens when you charge a QC3 device using a QC2 adapter?

I noticed several other questions on this StackExchange, but none of them seemed to answer this particular scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From  Qualcomm product manager, responsible for Quick Charge](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1293999)

> Of course, QC3 is backwards compatible to QC2 so your existing QC2 adapter will charge a QC3 phone and **vice versa**

(Emphasis supplied)

Thanks for asking this, I was under the impression that it is one way compatibility

Comment: Would appreciate your feedback once you use the charger please